# Why can't I alias this specially formatted date command?

Tags: bash, date, unix, alias

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. This is a specially formatted date command, and I'm trying to alias it to date. The error message I am getting is that the formats are not found.

This is the command -

```
alias date='date +'%A, %B %d, %Y - %r''
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a quoting problem. Your inner single quotes end your outer single quotes.

Choices:

1. Use double quotes on the alias:

   ```
   alias date="date '+%A, %B %d, %Y - %r'"
   ```
2. Use double quotes on the inner argument:

   ```
   alias date='date "+%A, %B %d, %Y - %r"'
   ```
3. "Escape" the inner single quotes:

   ```
   alias date='date '\''+%A, %B %d, %Y - %r'\'
   ```

And for completeness this (even uglier than the "escaped" single quotes) option (from chepner).

4. Escaped spaces instead of quoted spaces in the date argument:

   ```
   alias date='date +%A,\ %B\ %d,\ %Y\ -\ %r'
   ```

Comment: Or a really gross option 4, `alias date='date +%A,\ %B\ %d,\ %Y\ -\ %r'`

Comment: And if your backslash is busted, #3 could also be: `alias date='date '"'"'+%A, %B %d, %Y - %r'"'"`